# jquery.clone() attrs of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, vml

I create vml element v:shape, add styles and attributes, and then append it.

```
var shape = document.createElement("v:shape");
//some attrs
shape.setAttribute("coordorigin", "0 0");
shape.setAttribute("coordsize", w + " " + h);
shape.setAttribute("stroked", "false");
//...
//some styles
shape.style.position = "absolute";
shape.style.top = 0 + "px";
shape.style.left = 0 + "px";
shape.style.width = w + "px";
shape.style.height = h + "px";
//...
$(element).append(shape);
```

And I want to append the same shape to another place

```
var shape2 = $(shape).clone(true);
```

but it clones only styles

```
alert(shape2.css("position")); // absolute
alert(shape2.attr("coordsize")); // undefined
```

What sholuld I do? Help me please) 
**[EDIT]**
Thanks for your answers) Its weird for me... I noticed that it works when I append it to the element if `var element = document.createElement("p");` but I get my element by `$(selector).each(function(index, element) {` Even when I append it to the body it doesn't work(

Comment: Have you tried the `Node.cloneNode()` method?

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/GgVPU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me if I dummy in the missing values: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/hKCHX/1/ (Tried in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation ?

> .clone( [withDataAndEvents] )
>
> withDataAndEvents - A Boolean indicating
> whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements.
>
> .clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )
>
> withDataAndEvents - A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data
> should be copied along with the elements.
>
> The default value is false.
>
> deepWithDataAndEvents - A Boolean
> indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the
> cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the
> first argument's value (which defaults to false).

Using `clone(true)` will copy event handlers and data as well.

Here's a fiddle with your exact code (with minor changes) that works just fine [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GgVPU/1/)

Are you sure you have defined the `w`, `h` and `element` variables correctly, as `w` being `undefined` would cause the error you are getting ?